# How to convert list to row dataframe with Pandas

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, row

I have a list of items like this:

```
A = ['1', 'd', 'p', 'bab', '']
```

My goal is to convert such list into a dataframe of 1 row and 5 columns. If I type `pd.DataFrame(A)` I get 5 rows and 1 column. What should I do in order to get the result I want?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([A])
print (df)
   0  1  2    3 4
0  1  d  p  bab
```

If all values are strings:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(A).reshape(-1,len(A)))
print (df)

   0  1  2    3 4
0  1  d  p  bab
```

Thank you [AKS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42202872/how-to-convert-list-to-row-dataframe-with-pandas/42202892#comment71567050_42202892):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(A).T
print (df)
   0  1  2    3 4
0  1  d  p  bab
```

Comment: What about `pd.DataFrame(A).T`?

Comment: `pd.DataFrame([A])` converts list into a series, not a row.

Comment: Using pd.DataFrame(A).T can break dtypes.

Answer (score 37):

This is somewhat peripheral to your particular issue, but I figured I would post it in case it helps someone else out.

To convert a list of lists (and give each column a name), just pass the list to the data attribute (along with your desired column names) when instantiating the new dataframe, like so:

```
my_python_list = [['foo1', 'bar1'],
                  ['foo2', 'bar2']]
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['my_column_name_1', 'my_column_name_2'], data=my_python_list)
```

result:

```
  my_column_name_1 my_column_name_2
0             foo1             bar1
1             foo2             bar2
```