# Pandas DataFrame with row list and column list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list

I must be missing something, but I cannot find any guides on how to construct a pandas dataframe using both list of rows and columns. The purpose is that the `row_list` and `col_list` are updated in a loop and can hold more or less strings, but will always equal each other in length.

Using [transpose](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42202892/10859585) works on the rows, but I'm not sure how to pass the columns in.

```
row_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
col_list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
df = pd.DataFrame(row_list, columns=col_list)
>>>
raise ValueError(f"Shape of passed values is {passed}, indices imply {implied}")
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (4, 1), indices imply (4, 4)

df = pd.DataFrame(row_list).T
>>>
0 1 2 3
a b c d
```

Expected Output:

```
A B C D
a b c d
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap `row_list` in a list:

```
row_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
col_list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
df = pd.DataFrame([row_list], columns=col_list)

# or
df = pd.DataFrame([dict(zip(col_list, row_list))])
```

Although not recommended, the solution with the transpose would have been:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(row_list, index=col_list).T
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C  D
0  a  b  c  d
```

Comment: Why would you not recommend the transpose solution? Is it cumbersome with larger datasets?

Comment: It's less efficient and will mess up the dtypes if you have mixed dtypes (not in this case as your input is 1D).